# How to display the "Run" window all the time in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, output

I'm used to NetBeans, now I'm learning to use Android Studio, one thing annoying to me is : when I run the app, the "Run" window will disappear, and I have to click the "Run" button to see it every time, here are the screenshots, before I run the app, it looks like this :

[image]

After I click the following button :

[image]

The Run output window will automatically disappear, and the IDE will look like this at the bottom :

[image]

In NetBeans, when I run my app, the IDE will look the same and I don't have to click to see output window every time. I guess it's because I'm new to Android Studio and don't know how to make it not disappear, can some one tell me how to do it so every time when I run the app, the "Run" window will always be visible to see the output ?